# Is there any way I can run CMD as administrator without admin privileges

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have windows 10 , need to open CMD as admin o that i can change admin password 
.My lone admin account somehow changed to standard . Need to fix this issue .
When i boot in safe mode administrator account shows up asking for password , I believe i can change admin password by running cmd as admin and boot up again in safe mode and access the administrator account there . 
THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: "Running as admin" _means_ admin privileges.  Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

So this means you've locked yourself out of your admin account ?

If that's the case. There is a little trick you can use. Boot into a linux live system (partedmagic or anything else) then mount your Windows Partition. Navigate to system32 folder and search for cmd. Rename it to cmd2. then search for utilman.exe and rename it to cmd.exe rename cmd2 to utilman.exe and restart. Once done click the "Help Icon" on your lock screen. It will give you a cmd window with full admin permissions. Change Admin password and revert your changes

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Does this still work on Windows 10? I know I've used this trick on Vista and XP

Comment: It does still work.